# Entity Framework Core project's migration fails and debug profile does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, windows-10

I tried to create an `Entity Framework Core` migration but it fails. This is the output from the Visual Studio 2019 Package manager console

```
> Each package is licensed to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies that are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
>
> Package Manager Console Host Version 5.7.0.6726
>
> Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate

> Build started...  
> Build failed.
```

I then tried to build my code and got the following problem:
`debug profile does not exist`. How do I fix this problem? I have tried everything and I just can't seem to solve it.

Comment: Add-Migration attempts to build your solution first, but the build failed. Look at your Errors tab / build output to work out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you want to create an Entity Framework Core migration.

I assumed that you use sqlserver.

You can refer to the following steps to create the EF Core migration.

First, please create an console app(.Net Core).

Second,please install the following nuget packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Third, please add two classes to your console app.

```cs
public class Teacher
{
    public int TeaID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TeaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(@"Connectionstring");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>()
            .HasNoKey();
    }
}
```

The Connectionstring is the string that you connect to sql server database.(please create a database first)
Third, you can execute the following command in the Package manager console.

```
PM> Add-Migration Initial

PM> Update-Database
```

[image: Package Manager Console]

Finally, you can check the database design.

[image: Dtabase Desighn]

Comment: I fail to see how this helps OP with his build failures.

Comment: I jsut have one other question how do I add a debug profile

Comment: @TERMINATOR, you can right click the properties of the the app-> choose Debug->Click New.. to create a new debug profile.

Comment: Thanks helps so much keep on getting that error everywhere