# dotnet ef migrations add throws exception

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-core

I am using the following command in MacOS-Terminal;

`dotnet ef migrations add Student --project`

and got the exception "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
User-MacBook-Pro WebAPITutorial % dotnet ef migrations add Student --project
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.ParseOption(Boolean isLongOption, CommandLineApplication command, String[] args, Int32& index, CommandOption& option)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

Help me please.

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada I got the same exception

Comment: Please check https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

Comment: @mustafa, you can refer to the steps in the link [Entity Framework Core project's migration fails and debug profile does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63665700/11507778)  to 
 check if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify the project name (if want to store your migrations in a different project than the one containing your `DbContext`):

```
dotnet ef migrations add Student --project YourProjectName
```

Or if you are inside the project directory, there is no need to specify the project name:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Student
```